# How to count time on hover with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want when i hover on element to count 4 seconds for example and then do the action. But only if user really hover on that element 4 seconds, i dont want to use setTimeout function.

I found this example:

[How to check how long you hover an element in pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632626/how-to-check-how-long-you-hover-an-element-in-pure-javascript)

but this only count when user do mouseout. I want to do calculation on mouseover and if pass 4 seconds do something. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would say this is exactly the job for `setTimeout`. Only other thing with plain javascript would be `setInterval` with an interval of 1000ms an count to 4. Why can't you use `setTimeout`?

Comment: if i hover on element and use settimeout it will only delay some action which i want to do for 4 second...i want to check if user really hover on element 4 second and then call action...if im a littlebit clear what i want to achive ?

Comment: yes, got it. the function would still trigger if the user moves the mouse out of the object within the four second delay

Comment: yes..thats why settimeout is not good option for me :)

Comment: what about using mouseenter and mouseout instead? mouseenter to start the timer wtih 4 second delay, store the timer handle in a global variable. if the user leaves the object mouseout should be triggered and you can clear the timer handle before it triggers

Comment: i want something like tooltip where i will call external services..so when user hold mouse on that element i will call external service and display data in that tooltip...if i move mouse there is no point then to call service then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the previous answer with `setInterval`

```js
var handle = null

function enter() {
  handle = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('mouse in for 4s');
  }, 4000);
}
function out() {
  clearTimeout(handle);
}
```

```html
<button onmouseenter="enter()" onmouseout="out()">test</button>
```

Comment: [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example if the code not clear tell me in comment section, i will provide some more explanation if needed

```js
const button = document.getElementById("hover")
let date = null
let timer
button.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    if(!date) date = new Date()
    timer = setInterval(()=>{
        if((new Date() - date) >= 4000) {
        console.log('Do Action')
        clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }, 1000)
}, false)

button.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    clearInterval(timer)
    date = null
})
```

```html
<body>
    <button id='hover'>Hover Me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: even with one second hover it say do action ?

Comment: It needs 4 seconds, check it out run the snippet. that one sec in interval to check the time each one ec

Comment: Ohh one sec there something needs to be changed sorry

Comment: just to say i didnt give u -1 :)

Comment: I update it forgot to clear interval in mouseout . @None i hope it works for you